# How to logout specific User in Spring ? Programatically

Tags: java, spring, security, httpsession

So i have application where users can log in via social networks or normal login.
**I want to  be able to log into admin account and BAN a user, When i change status of user to Banned, I want to log him out via code!** How can i achieve that?

I added Session listener

```
    @Component
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static int totalActiveSessions;
    List<HttpSession> sessionList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static int getTotalActiveSession() {
        return totalActiveSessions;
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        totalActiveSessions++;
        if (sessionList.contains(httpSessionEvent.getSession())) {
            sessionList.add(httpSessionEvent.getSession());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        totalActiveSessions--;
        if (sessionList.contains(httpSessionEvent.getSession())) {
            sessionList.remove(httpSessionEvent.getSession());
        }
    }
}
```

**While debugging**  -  I dont know how to identify user, And also session seems to be created sooner then actually user logs in, just by visiting site, doesnt seem like proper way to do it.

Comment: It depends on what authentication method you're using. If you're using sessions directly you could track the sessions when the user logs in - at which point you should be able to identify the user as well. If you're using some token based mechanism like OAuth you could lock/ban the user in the identity provider and use very short lived authentication tokens (e.g. 5 minutes). That way the user should be logged out after a short time because refreshing the token would fail.

Comment: @aksappy how is it a duplicate? 2 different questions....

Comment: @Thomas I use both OAuth and basic , in basic i mean username password authentication that is from spring security by default. Dont know how that works exactly under the hood i was under impression that its using session to identify logged in user. Bud seems to me that when i debugged my breakpoint in adding new session was triggered before log in and not at all during login.

Comment: Well, in many applications you'll get a session right at the first request, i.e. before login. However, for security reasons you should get a new session after login, e.g. to prevent session fixation attacks etc. - You'd still have to track which sessions belong to which logged in user though.

Answer (score 4):

Create a meta user information model like

```
public class UserInfoContext implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String id;
private String name;
private String authType;

// more fields type of requirements

// Getter and Setters

// Constructor
```

}

At the time of both basic or OAuth authentication, put the meta information into this object and add this into the Session

```
UserInfoContext context = new UserInfoContext(id,name,type);

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttributes("UserContext",context);
```

The above session listener will be triggered when the session is created

You can get all the session list by setting getAllSessionList() in the SessionListener

```
public List<HttpSession> getAllSessionList(){
    return this.sessionList;
}
```

Suppose you want to ban a session and invalidate the user, when you are implementing the business logic get the particular session and 
invalidate it by using

```
session.invalidate();
```

Also tried to find the JSESSIONID id of the user and add it into the meta context class members, you can also need to invalidate it also

This may help you to get the required solution

Comment: Yes this looks like It should work, I will try it out or some variation of it , Bud this is def the approach I like.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a Servlet Filter to filter all the requests and see whether the user is active or not. Let me know if you need an example.